# How to connect to Mongodb with JDBC with server IP?

Tags: java, database, mongodb

The purpose is to connect MongoDB remote server through Java.
Below is the code I'm using.
Tried Unity_trial.Jar, mongo_version.jar files but the error comes is also below and the server details are also provided.

```java
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://myUserAdmin:abc123@admin.34.69.114.142:27017/?authSource=db1&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("My3kart_S1");
MongoIterable<String> mongoIterable =mongoDatabase.listCollectionNames();
MongoCursor<String> iterator =  mongoIterable.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}

mongoClient.close();
```

```
    Server Details
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1337            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17579/node /home/nx
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
    tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
    tcp6       0      0 :::3004                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
    tcp6       0      0 :::3005                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
    tcp6       0      0 :::8004                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
    tcp6       0      0 :::8005                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Error message is:

> main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[admin.34.69.114.142:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
> [cluster-ClusterId{value='5fd0677b97cb070f9848cdbe', description='null'}-admin.34.69.114.142:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server admin.34.69.114.142:27017
> com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: No such host is known (admin.34.69.114.142)

Comment: You have provided a host name of `admin.34.69.114.142`. I assume the public IP address of the server is actually `34.69.114.142` - so maybe use that instead. Otherwise you need to locate the actual public IP address - or, better yet, the full host name of the server.

Comment: Ive tried with just 34.69.114.142, no luck